# Message in console.log is not showed anything i proved

Tags: reactjs, console.log

i'm roking in a ASP.NET CORE MVC project and i have a React class that is a component used in a razor page.

I tried in every single way that i found in the web but seems like console.log don't show anything.

The component is render on the page and shows the properties correctly:

[image]

and this is the inspector:
[image]

```
class App extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('hi')
    }
    
    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        const { Property1, Property2 } = this.props

        const handler = (event) => {
            console.log(event);
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={handler}> clicca </button>
                {console.log(this.props)}
                <p>Property1: {Property1}</p>
                <p>Property2: {Property2}</p>
                <div className="box">Sono un box</div>
            </div>

            );
    }
}
```

Non of them works and i don't understand why

Index.cshtml (just a simple page with the component)

```
@Html.React("App",new { Property1 = "value1", Property2 = "value2" })


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js"></script>
```

Program.cs:

```
 //configure the services for application
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

        builder.Services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

        //builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();  
        builder.Services.AddReact();
        builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();


        builder.Services.AddJsEngineSwitcher(option => option.DefaultEngineName = V8JsEngine.EngineName).AddV8();
        
        
        var app = builder.Build();
        // configure middleware
        
        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseReact(config => {
            config.AddScript("~/js/App.jsx");
        });
        
        ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration.JsonSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();

        
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        app.Run();
    }
```

[EDIT]
with ReactInitJavascript at the end of the Index.cshtml when i start the page, data are showen like the component was loaded correcty, but in the inspectore says that component App is not defined.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title> - SportData</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/site.css?v=_5WottCwlLwmnX08KuvZv3ryqfP5c42il12e6LRxHqg" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/card.css?v=ZXutknPLolnM8AJ6Dofwp6kVw_54LAeyyWSi8YLbEeY" />
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            

<div id="react_0HMO2J0AM8AAV"><div data-reactroot=""><button> clicca </button><p>Property1: <!-- -->value1</p><p>Property2: <!-- -->value2</p><div class="box">Sono un box</div></div></div>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js"></script>

<script>ReactDOM.hydrate(React.createElement(App, {"Property1":"value1","Property2":"value2"}), document.getElementById("react_0HMO2J0AM8AAV"));
</script> --> this is the error line
                    
        </main>
    </div>
  

    <script src="/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
    

<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_vs/browserLink" async="async" id="__browserLink_initializationData" data-requestId="6501a3e3c110465981ca8b97a81c1842" data-requestMappingFromServer="false" data-connectUrl="http://localhost:57481/dc7f1eca94044a1ca53edfa6de85d80f/browserLink"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

<script src="/_framework/aspnetcore-browser-refresh.js"></script></body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check the Javascript console for errors. Get in the habit of reading errors, don't ignore them. It also sounds like your `App` component might not be rendering, but you don't show us how you actually use the `App` component. Please edit the question  (don't comment) to add that, or your question may be closed.

Comment: @AndyRay I updated my question with more information. Thanks.

Comment: Your component is rendering server side only, and returning the rendered HTML string to the page. Please read the documentation on how to do this properly, you're not calling `ReactInitJavaScript`. https://reactjs.net/features/server-side-rendering.html

Comment: I added 'Html.ReactInitJavaScript()' to my Index.cshtml but now, in the console, says that can't find the App component while data are showen. However, console don't print yet.  @AndyRay

Comment: @AndyRay I figure out that the problem is that i don't use correctly se client-side. But, i can't find a way to use the console log, because if i put ReactInitJavascript, inspector says that the component is undefined and the class has Ract.Component undefined. Would you suggest me what i have to modify in the App.jsx and Layout.cshtml (or Inde.cshtml idk) to solve the problem?

Comment: i tried to better exspose my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75284348/how-to-implement-client-side-on-asp-net-core-mvc-project-with-ractjs-component

if i have to delete this question, ill'do. Thanks