# How to implement client-side on ASP.NET CORE MVC project with RactJS Component

Tags: reactjs, client-side, console.log

**[EDIT]**
Ok, i unstertood that, if i render my class in a div with id="root" using ReactDOM.render it work and i can use console.log().
But i need that this component, that is in a Razor pages, could be receive ,as props, some data of the Razor's Model. (for example a list of users). So, i decided to use @Html.React to load the component. But if i use this method, i can pass properties but console.log() doesn't work.
What should i do?
And, there is a way which i can use, in the razor pages, the component as "" ??

**[EDIT]**
i want to do something like that but the component are not showing anymore.

```
<div id="root">
    <App/>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js")"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/js/app.jsx")" type="text/babel"></script>
```

i have an ASP.NET CORE MVC project and i want that my Razor pages implement ReactJS component.
I can load the component App but when i tried to use console.log it doens't work. I figure out that is because the component load only on server side but i can't find a correct way to allow my client-side to access to component and use the js to print in the console a value that i want.

First solution i tried was by follow this link: https://reactjs.net/features/server-side-rendering.html

But when it says to add :

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/main")
@Html.ReactInitJavaScript()
```

I have 2 problem:

1. don't foud @Script so i had to install WebOptimize..but now it says that cannot fine the Ihtml string
2. i don't have this  '~/bundles/main', what is that file? i have to install packages?
3. with ReactInitJavaScript component is showen but in the inspector says that component is undefined and in the class cannot find React.Component

So, the value are showen but i can't access to console. What i have to insert in the code to enable the client-side??

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - SportData</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/card.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>
<body>
     
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
    </div>
  

    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    
    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>

</html>
```

Index.cshtml

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json;
@using SportData.Web.Models;
@using System.Web.Optimization;


@model SportContainer


@Html.React("App",new { Property1 = "value1", Property2 = "value2" })

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/remarkable/1.7.1/remarkable.min.js"></script>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/main")
@Html.ReactInitJavaScript()
```

App.jsx:

```
class App extends React.Component{

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('hi')
    }
    
    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        const { Property1, Property2 } = this.props

        const handler = (event) => {
            console.log(event);
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={handler}> clicca </button>
                {console.log(this.props)}
                <p>Property1: {Property1}</p>
                <p>Property2: {Property2}</p>
                <div className="box">Sono un box</div>
            </div>

            );
    }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        
        // Add services to the container.
        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

        builder.Services.AddMvc().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

        //builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();  
        builder.Services.AddReact();
        builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        
        builder.Services.AddJsEngineSwitcher(option => option.DefaultEngineName = V8JsEngine.EngineName).AddV8();
        
        
        var app = builder.Build();
        // configure middleware
        
        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseReact(config => {
            config.AddScript("~/js/App.jsx");
        });
        
        ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration.JsonSerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();

        
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use react js with api this is way.because if you will use react js like this you cannot make rich ui and also issues with the packges but if you want to use like this so you have to use like this.
[check here](https://www.letsreact.org/how-to-create-a-react-app-without-npm/)

Comment: Basically, i have to use "@Html.React()" in my index.cshtml and in the class component, render the same class in a div on to Layout.cshtml...Otherwise i can't access to the console.log, right?

Comment: Doesn't work beacuse if i put ReactDOM....the function can't find the document.

Comment: ok first you have to under stand that you embed the react as js library for the razor pages you have to  add the  js file  in script section that's all.

Comment: do not use @Htm.React() because it will make the thing  complex and not working for you so also you just add the js library and do all stuff routing every thing using  react

Comment: So, every time i want a component in my razor page i have to use ReactDOM.render and have a div to contain it. But, there is a way to use the component as a tag?  for example: ""<App/>", just to not have a render script for every time a want a component.

Comment: i updated the question to show you what i want to do, but i don't know if it's a good solution or i'm wasting time over futher details. Thanks.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience but I want to just explain you have only one razor page which contain your react library and configuration and  then you will use react components.